# Postgresql Constraints (display)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to display the list of integrity constraints of my solution by indicating the name of the constraint, its type and the detail of the constraint (message that explains what validates the constraint), all sorted by table name and constraint name.

This is what I tried :

```
SELECT constraint_name, constraint_type
FROM user_constraints
WHERE table_name = 'mytable'
```

How can I display all of that and also give a message that indicates what validates the constraint ?

Comment: Great question! Tables have 11+1 types of constraints. Writing the query to retrieve them all and also to render them in readable language is probably tedious albeit totally feasible. I'll pay attention to the answers since it may come in handy for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to list all constraints of a table in PostgreSQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/214863/how-to-list-all-constraints-of-a-table-in-postgresql)

Comment: How do you find the <schema name> ? @Schwern

Comment: @fenton.raine If you don't know your schema you're using the default schema "public". See https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-schema/

Comment: @fenton.raine Do you mind if I start a bounty for this question? I would love to see a good answer for it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a comment that doesn't fit the comments section.

I wanted to document that tables have 11+1 types of constraints:

1. Table `PRIMARY KEY` constraint.
2. Table `UNIQUE` constraint.
3. Table `CHECK` constraint.
4. Table [imported] `FOREIGN KEY` constraint (aka reference).
5. Table [exported] `FOREIGN KEY` constraint (aka referential action `RESTRICT`).
6. Column `NOT NULL` constraint.
7. Column `PRIMARY KEY` constraint.
8. Column `UNIQUE` constraint.
9. Column `CHECK` constraint.
10. Column [imported] `FOREIGN KEY` constraint (aka reference).
11. Column [exported] `FOREIGN KEY` constraint (aka referential action `RESTRICT`).
12. The "Partial UNIQUE INDEX" pseudo constraint, when adding `WHERE` to the `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ...` statement. This type of constraints is, however, debated since the SQL Standard does not include it. In practice all major database engines (Oracle, DB2, PostgreSQL, etc.) implement them (albeit using different strategies) and they are very efficiently at maintaining data quality.

**Note**: Some engines (e.g. Oracle) do not implement #7 to #11. For Oracle most constraints are recorded at the table level, even if you define them at the column level.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query (This query is tested on MS SQL, I hope you convert it for PostgreSQL):

```
Select self_objects.name 'Table_Name', C.*, (Select definition From sys.default_constraints Where object_id = C.object_id) As dk_definition,
(Select definition From sys.check_constraints Where object_id = C.object_id) As ck_definition,
(Select name From sys.objects Where object_id = D.referenced_object_id) As fk_table,
(Select name From sys.columns Where column_id = D.parent_column_id And object_id = D.parent_object_id) As fk_col
From sys.objects As C
join sys.objects self_objects on
self_objects.object_id = c.parent_object_id
and self_objects.type = 'U'
Left Join (Select * From sys.foreign_key_columns) As D On D.constraint_object_id = C.object_id 
order by self_objects.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code.

```sql
SELECT
    "ns"."nspname" AS "table_schema",
    "t"."relname" AS "table_name",
    "cnst"."conname" AS "constraint_name", pg_get_constraintdef ( "cnst"."oid" ) AS "expression",
CASE
        "cnst"."contype" 
        WHEN 'p' THEN
        'PRIMARY' 
        WHEN 'u' THEN
        'UNIQUE' 
        WHEN 'c' THEN
        'CHECK' 
        WHEN 'x' THEN
        'EXCLUDE' 
    END AS "constraint_type",
    "a"."attname" AS "column_name"
FROM
    "pg_constraint" "cnst" 
    INNER JOIN "pg_class" "t" ON "t"."oid" = "cnst"."conrelid"
    INNER JOIN "pg_namespace" "ns" ON "ns"."oid" = "cnst"."connamespace"
    LEFT JOIN "pg_attribute" "a" ON "a"."attrelid" = "cnst"."conrelid" 
    AND "a"."attnum" = ANY ( "cnst"."conkey" )
```

Comment: Your answer is not complete but it's a start. I didn't want the bounty go to waste so I assigned it to you.