# Oracle SQL create unique INDEX constraint based on status column and other 4 column

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

I need  UNIQUE INDEX CONSTRAINT for below example:

```
 CREATE TABLE DEMO(
    
    COL_1 number,
    COL_2 number,
    COL_3 number,
    COL_4 number,
    STATUS number)
    ;
    
    Insert into DEMO(COL_1,COL_2,COL_3,COL_4,STATUS) values (1,2,3,4,0); --Allow insert
    Insert into DEMO(COL_1,COL_2,COL_3,COL_4,STATUS) values (1,2,3,4,1); --Allow insert
    Insert into DEMO(COL_1,COL_2,COL_3,COL_4,STATUS) values (1,2,3,4,0); --Allow insert
    Insert into DEMO(COL_1,COL_2,COL_3,COL_4,STATUS) values (1,2,3,4,1); --Not allow insert status 1 already exits!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the 12th **pseudo** constraint (based on [constraint types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69399932/postgresql-constraints-display/69400028#69400028)) that you can impose on a database model, that doesn't require the use of the clause `CONSTRAINT` to define it.

You can create a partial unique index to enforce it. For example:

```
create unique index ix1 on demo (
  case when status = 1 then col_1 end,
  case when status = 1 then col_2 end, 
  case when status = 1 then col_3 end,
  case when status = 1 then col_4 end,
  case when status = 1 then status end
);
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=77d516ee90607b49e2c9399ac7ca0069).

Comment: Tnx for help but  Insert into DEMO(COL_1,COL_2,COL_3,COL_4,STATUS) values (1,2,3,5,1);   --Not allow col_4 is different

Comment: @Pointer That last insert works well, and I understand the OP does want it to be inserted, doesn't he? See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6862104e06d40460e0ab5b8b1d429f78

Answer (score 0):

You simply need a conditional index on the STATUS column. You can try below query -

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UNQ_IDX_STATUS ON DEMO (CASE WHEN STATUS = 1 THEN STATUS ELSE NULL END);
```

This will only apply the constraint where the STATUS column will have the value as 1 else will have no impact on your other values in this column.

Comment: I think the OP also wants to include the first 4 columns in the index.

Comment: @Ankit Bajpai  Your example not allow  Insert into DEMO(COL_1,COL_2,COL_3,COL_4,STATUS) values (1,2,3,9,1);

Answer (score 0):

you could try this also, by creating a unique index which is a concenate of the columns.

```
CREATE   TABLE DEMO(
    COL_1 number(1),
    COL_2 number(1),
    COL_3 number(1),
    COL_4 number(1),
    STATUS number(1))
;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UQ_INDEX
ON DEMO(
(     CASE STATUS WHEN  1        THEN COL_1 || COL_2 ||COL_3 ||COL_4 ||STATUS 
     ELSE
         NULL
 END));

Insert into DEMO(COL_1,COL_2,COL_3,COL_4,STATUS) values (1,2,3,4,0); 
Insert into DEMO(COL_1,COL_2,COL_3,COL_4,STATUS) values (1,2,3,4,1);
Insert into DEMO(COL_1,COL_2,COL_3,COL_4,STATUS) values (1,2,3,4,0);
Insert into DEMO(COL_1,COL_2,COL_3,COL_4,STATUS) values (1,2,3,4,1);
```